# padding a string with zeros and passing it to another page in asp.net webforms

Tags: c#, asp.net, formatting

I'm trying to pad a textbox value with zeros and pass it to another page with Response.Redirect in asp.net webforms. I cannot get the number to be padded with zeros. If I enter 2 in the textbox it should display 000002 on the second page. Here's my code:

```
if (cmbSearchBy.Text == "Account Number")
{
    var zeropadding = String.Format("{0:00000}", txtSearchKeyword.Text);
    Response.Redirect("AccountTable.aspx?SearchBy=" + cmbSearchBy.SelectedValue + "&TableSelection=" + cmbSelectTable.SelectedValue + "&SearchTerm=" + zeropadding + "");
}
else
{
    Response.Redirect("AccountTable.aspx?SearchBy=" + cmbSearchBy.SelectedValue + "&TableSelection=" + cmbSelectTable.SelectedValue + "&SearchTerm=" + txtSearchKeyword.Text + "");
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the values are all strings, you don't need to use `String.Format()` like you would with numeric values.  You can use [the `.PadLeft()` method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.padleft) instead.  Something like this:

```
var zeropadding = txtSearchKeyword.Text.PadLeft(6, '0');
```

This would pad the value with `'0'` on the left to a total width of 6.  (Or simply return the string if it's already 6 characters or more.)